# Odata How to return anonymous type from a function

Tags: c#, function, return, odata, anonymous

I want to return an anonymous type from a function in an Odata driver. But I'm getting a 406 error.

This is my function in the WebApiConfig:

```
builder.Function("TestFunction")
                       .Returns<Object>();
```

This is my method in the Odata controller

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("TestFunction")]
public IHttpActionResult TestFunction()
{
    var created = (from RI in db.RequestInstance
                         join RVI in db.RequestVersionInstance on RI.ActualRequestVersionInstanceID equals RVI.RequestVersionInstanceID
                         join RS in db.RequestState on RVI.RequestStateID equals RS.RequestStateID
                         where RI.ClientUserID == userDepartmentId && RVI.RequestStateID == 1
                         group RI by new { RI.RequestInstanceID, RS.Name, RS.Color } into C
                         select new DashBoardFilter()
                         {
                             Name = C.Key.Name,
                             Color = C.Key.Color,
                             Quantity = C.Count()
                         }
           ).Single();
    var select= (from RI in db.RequestInstance
                                     join RVI in db.RequestVersionInstance on RI.ActualRequestVersionInstanceID equals RVI.RequestVersionInstanceID
                                     join RS in db.RequestState on RVI.RequestStateID equals RS.RequestStateID
                                     where RI.ClientUserID == userDepartmentId && RVI.RequestStateID == 2
                                     group RI by new { RI.RequestInstanceID, RS.Name, RS.Color } into C
                                     select new DashBoardFilter()
                                     {
                                         Name = C.Key.Name,
                                         Color = C.Key.Color,
                                         Quantity = C.Count()
                                     }
                       ).Single();
    return Ok(new { Created = created, Select = select});
}
```

I hope you can help me

Thanks

Comment: Which version of OData are you using?

Comment: Hi, Dido, the version is OData 6

Comment: Try creating a new class `TestResult` that has two properties: `Created` and `Select`. The types of those properties should be the same as the types of `created` and `select`. Register `TestResult` as a `ComplexType` in `builder` and then change `TestFunction` to return `TestResult`. Do a `GET` and tell me if it worked.

Comment: But that will force me to have a dedicated type for each combination of objects. Anonymous works for that. It can not be that OData does not work with anonymous. There is some other option.

Comment: The OData formatter does not know how to serialize the anonymous object you're passing to it, hence it returns 406. If you don't want to have concrete types for each function or action, try using an open type that has a property of type `Dictionary<string, object>`.